# How to use different banner sliders for different store views in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, store-view, slider, banner-slider

I am trying to make a Hindi version of my website.

**Things I am able to do:**

1. Create a store view and use a different Locale setting for it.
2. Add different products for the different views, with translated keywords such as "Payment", "Add to cart", "Checkout" and stuff.

**Thing I am stuck at:**

My original store had a bannerslider (Magestore), and I want to display different images on the slider, when the Hindi website is selected.

But unfortunately, the **view settings** of the **"Manage Banners"** in the "top left corner" doesn't work.

Those settings aren't there in the **Manage Slider** settings, so I can't create a different slider for it.

I tried creating a different homepage from the CMS for the hindi website, but I can't really think of how to integrate a different slider for it.

Any help would be needed.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the extension you are using for banners?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I am using the Magestore bannerslider (as mentioned in the original post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the module we use for creating sliding banners https://github.com/alexryall/magento-slider

You can then create a new CMS page, insert a banner widget and assign the new page as the homepage for the new store view in Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page